# Callback context with promise/async-await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, ecmascript-2016

I am trying to use the ES7 async-await feature to avoid callback hell in some of my code. I am using SQLite and I need to access a variable in the context of the callback.

To illustrate, here is the thing, from the sqlite3 npm module:

```js
module.exports = function() {
  db.run("INSERT INTO foo ...", function(err) {
    // err is null if insertion was successful
    console.log("inserted id:", this.lastID);
  });
};
```

Let's assume I created a promise running the above code, how can I access the `this.lastID` with the async-await feature?

```js
module.exports = async function() {
  try {
    await db.run("INSERT INTO foo ...");
    // How can I access the `this` context?
  } catch (err) {
  }
};
```

Comment: What does `this` refer here?

Comment: Are you sure that `db.run` does return a promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a smart promisified version of `db.run`:

```babel
db.runAsync = function(query) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.run(query, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      reject(err)
    } else {
      resolve(this)
    }
  }))
}
```

Then you'll be able to use this `runAsync` to access `this` context from your async-await code:

```babel
let res = await db.runAsync('INSERT INTO foo ...')
console.log(`inserted id: ${res.lastID}`)
```

Comment: `ninvoke` will not `resolve` resulting promise with `this`.